# Matched panel data regression in R: clustering on three dimensions (firm_id, year, matching value) with plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm new to working with panel data in general. While I work with R my coauthors work with Stata. So naturally, I'm running into problems that they can't relate to but I also can't fully explain them my problem due to a limited understanding of panel data econometrics. I tried to solve the issue below by consulting: [http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101R.pdf](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/Panel101R.pdf) and some other resources on the *plm package* but failed.

The data is structured like this:

- firms with fof dummy '1' have been propensity score-matched with similar firms with fof '0' based on total assets, operating revenue, and number of employees
- each subclass contains one firm with fof '1' and 2-10 matched firms with fof '0', i.e. it is unbalanced
- for every firm, I have data for nine years (2013-2021), or at least most of the years

What I'm trying to get working is a panel (indexed/pooled/clustered by firm_id and year) regression which compares firms **per subclass** so to estimate the effect of the fof dummy on performance in comparison to the matched firms while controlling for the influence of differences in matching variables. Hausman test indicates that a random effect model should be used but the fixed effect model does not even provide an estimate for the fof variable.

When using "test" instead of the panel data "p_test" (i.e. not declaring it a panel dataframe), then clustering on subclass works but I'm not sure whether this then disregards the panel structure of the data. But using "p_test" seems to completely ignore subclass because it treats every row as an independent observation while they actually should be correlated within each firm.

My questions are:
a) Is this even the right approach to handle the data? Or should it only be clustered at firm & year?
b) Is there a way to solve this in R or should I just give in and use Stata instead of R?
I'm puzzled and would appreciate any help out there. Thanks so much in advance!

````
# Declare the data frame as a panel data frame
p_test <- pdata.frame(test, index = c("firm_id", "year"))

#regressions
test.fe <- plm(ROA_preTax ~ fof + log1p(total_assets) + log1p(operating_revenue_turnover) 
                + log1p(number_of_employees),
                data = p_test,
                model = "within",
                effect = "twoways",
               index = "subclass")
summary(test.fe)
test.re <- plm(ROA_preTax ~ fof + log1p(total_assets) + log1p(operating_revenue_turnover) 
                + log1p(number_of_employees),
                data = p_test,
                model = "random",
                effect = "twoways",
               index = "subclass")
summary(test.re)```
````

Comment: Once you provide a pdata.frame to `plm()`, supplying an `index` argument to `plm()` does not make sense as it is ignored. Instead, subset your pdata.frame `p_test` accordingly and feed it to `plm()`. Be sure to use `summary()` on the estimated model object to see how many observations (and invidiual and time stamps) are used and esp. if these figures correspond to what you have in mind when looking at subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, Helix123 for the quick reply. I tried supplying subclass to the pdata.frame originally as well but then the fof estimate in the fixed effect model disappears, so I'm left without the main IV and I can't figure out why that is.
using `summary()` function: Did this, which is why I tried using the additional index argument in `plm()`. It seems that only when using subclass as index, the observations are n= #fof and then treat all matched firms as different time stamps because I get T=1-99. When supplying subclass as a third argument to the pdata.frame, I get n=#fof+#non-fof while T=1-9.